# Caffeine's role in fat oxidation

Tags: body-fat, caffeine

Seen here:
http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/79/1/40.full

It is stated:

> In agreement with the results of previous studies (1, 20), the present
>   study showed that caffeine ingestion increased energy expenditure
>   (≈13%) and lipid turnover and oxidation. However, the contribution of
>   nonoxidative lipid disposal was much greater (76%) than that of lipid
>   oxidation (24%).

So my question is what's the difference between *nonoxidative lipid disposal* vs *lipid oxidation*, and how does that effect someone trying to burn fat?